# How to run url in background of chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, linkedin-api

I am trying to make a chrome plugin for linkedin job search. To run the linkedin javascript api it requires a domian, so for development i used localhost. Now when the chrome pluging is clicked it opens a new tab with the localhost url and does the jobs search with linked API.
Now i want the url page to run in the backgrowd of the plugin to get the latest jobs updates. but the manifest doesn't loads the url page in background.

here's my `manifest.json` file

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Hunt Shire",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "This is a login plugin.",
  "background":{           
       "page": "http://localhost:82/Plugin.html"        
   },
  "browser_action":
   {          
        "defaul_title":"HuntShire",
        "default_icon":"Hunt logo.png"
   },
  "permissions": ["tabs",
              "notifications",
              "https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js"
              ],
   "web_accessible_resources":["Hunt Logo.png"]

 }
```

Is there anyway to run it or any other way to run a background script for a particular domain reference.

here's some of the script of the `http://localhost:82/Plugin.html` which fetches the data with the linked API.

```
   api_key: xxxxxxxxxxx
   onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
   authorize: true
   function onLinkedInLoad() {
        IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", onLinkedInAuth);
    };

    function onLinkedInAuth() {
        IN.API.Profile("me").fields(["id", "firstName", "lastName", "emailAddress",      "positions:(company)", "following"]).result(displayProfiles);
    };
   // some more query.
```

but if i do this in some other local html file it gives me an error
`Uncaught Error: JavaScript API Domain is restricted to localhost`.
please give me some hint.

Thanks.

Comment: depending on the API, you might be able to use a Worker to make the IO happen and postMessage the results back to your app.

Comment: Can you please explain me a bit, how to run it in background.

Comment: got a meeting, sorry. checkout http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external.html for most of what i'd say anyway...

Answer (score -1):

For

```
 Uncaught Error: JavaScript API Domain is restricted to localhost
```

Go to your application made in linkedin and in javascript option sdk the added url is of localhost and another url there.